# Laravel & jQuery check all check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-4

On my page I have several checkboxes defined as follows:

```
<input id="{{ $question->id }}" class="questionCheckBox" type="checkbox" />
```

I have two buttons:

```
<p><input type="button" class="check" value="Check All" />
   <input type="button" class="uncheck" value="UnCheck All" />
</p>
```

I am trying to check all the check boxes or uncheck them all using the following code

```
$(function () {
    $('.check').on('click', function () {
        $('.questionCheckBox').attr('checked','checked');
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.uncheck').on('click', function () {
        $('.questionCheckBox').removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

The first time I click the check all button it works, the first time I check the uncheck button all is unchecked; after that neither button works. Can someone see my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
$(function () {
    $('.check').on('click', function () {
        $('.questionCheckBox').each(function(){ this.checked = true; });
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.uncheck').on('click', function () {
        $('.questionCheckBox').each(function(){ this.checked = false; });
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prop(`) instead of `attr()` as the latest verion of jQuery 1.9+ give similar kind of problem.

```
$(function () {
    $('.check').on('click', function () {
        $('.questionCheckBox').prop('checked',true);
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('.uncheck').on('click', function () {
        $('.questionCheckBox').prop('checked',false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works once, I have gone to similar situation.